# WinSCP - edit connection config file?

Tags: winscp

Is there a way to edit all the connections and related parameters in a text file rather than using the GUI?  I have maybe 15-20 to enter, and could add them from a spreadsheet, probably faster in a text edit mode.  Also, there is a pattern in our naming, so many of the parameters are the same (userid, keyfile name, similar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WinSCP can [load configuration from an INI file](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/config).

You can edit the INI file like:

```
[Sessions\Server1]
HostName=server1
UserName=user1
PasswordPlain=password1
FSProtocol=2

[Sessions\Server2]
HostName=server2
UserName=user2
PasswordPlain=password2
FSProtocol=2
```